# Database - table contain only primary and foreign keys

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-normalization

Can a table contain only a primary key and 1 or more foreign keys? Or it will violate the normalization design?

For example:

PK: SKILL_NAME
FK: SKILL_ID
FK: EMPL_ID

Comment: Hi. Why would it? Why wouldn't it? Learn what normalization is & don't worry about things that you wonder might have to do with it when you don't know what it is. An answer to this question is a chapter of a textbook plus a bespoke tutorial--it is "too broad" for SO. It is nevertheless also a duplicate. PS FKs have nothing to do with what NF a table is in. PKs are irrelevant to normalization except that they are CKs & CKs matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a database table that contains only primary and foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41272387/3404097)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This would be the typical structure, for instance, for an association/junction table that implements a n-m relationship between two entities.

That said, almost all tables I create also have:

- `createdAt` -- insertion time for the record
- `createdBy` -- who inserted the record

And sometimes:

- `createdOn` -- the system/database where the record was created

Answer (score 0):

Your example may not be a good one because i don't understand the scenario that skill_name is the PK, instead of skill_id.

What you mentioned is actually similar to EAV data model, i see some open source produce (magento) using it. But it's too normalized and need denormalized caching table for the performance.